# Populate parent Object by comparing parent Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Am having an arrray of Objects which again contains the id's of the parent Object:
eg:-

```
$scope.result=[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": ABC,
    "type": PQR,
    "parentId": 2
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": ABC,
    "type": PQR,
    "parentId": 1
}]
```

I would like to convert this JSON in to the following wherin I will be having the parentObject in place of parentId's

```
$scope.result=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": ABC,
        "type": a,
        "parentId": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": PQR,
            "type": b,
            "parentId": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": PQR,
        "type": b,
        "parentId": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": ABC,
            "type": a
        }
    }
]
```

Can anybody help me with this conversion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `parentId` will reference to one element

```
angular.forEach($scope.result, function(result) {
   var obj = $scope.result.filter(function(ele) {
         return result.parentId === ele.id;
   })[0];
   result.parentId = obj;
});
```

Since your tags doesn't contain angularjs, I'm using `Array.prototype.forEach` here

```
$scope.result.forEach(function(result) {
   var obj = $scope.result.filter(function(ele) {
         return result.parentId === ele.id;
   })[0];
   result.parentId = obj;
});
```

Comment: We will be having the final array in $scope.result right?

Comment: Yes, it will be in $scope.result. I've made one change in the above code. Please test the latest code

Comment: Am getting parentId as undefined

Comment: Using `filter` to find a single item in an array will be really inefficient, it will need to iterate over the entire array once for every item in the array! If the data-set it is using grows to even a modestly large size this will get real slow real fast. A better way would be to use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if targeting ES6 compatible browsers and/or using a ES6 to ES5 transpiler. Or you could always just use a plain old `for` loop with a `break` statement when you find the id you are looking for.

Comment: @UselessCode Yup, I agree to your point. Better to use for loop with break statement as of now..

Answer (score 1):

Will do 2 loops first one to fill a hash with keys of the ids, second will loop to replace parent id with actual object:

```
$scope = {}
$scope.result=[
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "ABC",
  "type": "PQR",
  "parentId": 2
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "ABC",
  "type": "PQR",
  "parentId": 1
}]

parents = {}
for(i=0;i<$scope.result.length;i++){
  parents[$scope.result[i]["id"]] = jQuery.extend({}, $scope.result[i]); // Clone object
}

 for(i=0;i<$scope.result.length;i++){
  $scope.result[i]["parentId"] = parents[$scope.result[i]["parentId"]]
}

$scope.result
```